# XSLT - multiple elements values are coming in single read

Tags: xslt

I am trying to read the number element value using below xsl.

**XML:**

```
<message channel-id="64E523E5-7A27-4343-A62A-AA8FBD24EB59">
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <insertResponse>    
     <sys_id>4342e2a24fb142005b0e4fe18110c7f3</sys_id>
     <number>INC0010038</number>
  </insertResponse>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
</message>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
     <message>
       <send-parameters>
         <agent-parameter>
           <name>IncidentNumber</name>
           <value><xsl:value-of select="message/s:Envelope/s:Body/t:insertResponse/t:number" /></value>
         </agent-parameter>
       </send-parameters>
     </message>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output i am getting is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <message>
   <send-parameters>
      <agent-parameter>
          <name>IncidentNumber</name>
          <value>4342e2a24fb142005b0e4fe18110c7f3
INC0010038</value>
      </agent-parameter>
   </send-parameters>
</message>
```

The value element is getting value from both sys-id and number tags **4342e2a24fb142005b0e4fe18110c7f3INC0010038**. I want to read only number tag from the xml. I am sure that i am missing something very basic here. Please help me with that.

Regards,
Kiran

Comment: "*The output i am getting is as below.*" No, i don't think so. The output here is an error caused by undeclared namespace prefixes in the stylesheet. Your input is not well-formed, either..

Comment: Modified the input xml. There was an > missing in the initial xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="env xsl">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <message>
      <send-parameters>
        <agent-parameter>
          <name>IncidentNumber</name>
          <value>
            <xsl:value-of select="message/env:Envelope/env:Body/insertResponse/number" />
          </value>
        </agent-parameter>
      </send-parameters>
    </message>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As stated by Micheal you are missing namespace definition in your stylesheet. Once you do that your code is good to go

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked very well. Really appreciate your input.